# How to rollback code visual basic

Tags: visual-studio

I created a program in visual basic and I published a few different versions of it and my current code isn't working and I want to rollback to my previous version.

I have no ad-dons or extensions or plugins.

Comment: Without some version control application - you can't

Comment: what if i have a previous version of the program is there a way that i can dissect it can something?

Comment: You can reverse engineer your published exe/dll with .net reflector. Check out [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/). However it would be easier just fix your existing code, and start using some version control system...

Comment: It's sad not to read the first section of _The Pragmatic Programmer: From Journeyman to Master_ before you start coding.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot do it easily. You could "decompile" your working assembly and try to find what's changed in relevant sections, but keep in mind that such programs' output does not contain comments or syntactic constructs so it will be hard to read. I'm afraid that's the best you can do at this point. I had good experience with [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/download/), but there are many such tools.

As for what is **most** important for you to start doing as soon as possible, look into version control systems. There is no better time to start than now. I recommend starting with `git` as it is popular, very powerful, lightweight and has tools and documentation to help you get into it. Also, you do not need to set up any servers, you can keep it all on you local computer, but it could be beneficial to host your code on one of open hosting sites, like github.